# multiple NS records and modern web browsers

Tags: domain-name-system

Folks,
  How do modern browsers react to the existence of multiple NS records?
  For example, amazon

```
amazon.com  nameserver = ns3.p31.dynect.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = ns4.p31.dynect.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns5.ultradns.info.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns2.ultradns.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns1.ultradns.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = ns1.p31.dynect.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns6.ultradns.co.uk.
amazon.com  nameserver = ns2.p31.dynect.net.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns4.ultradns.org.
amazon.com  nameserver = pdns3.ultradns.org.
```

Does this mean that web browsers chose one of the above NS servers at random?

Comment: Browsers don't do anything. The operating system's resolver does.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I stand corrected.  What happens at the tcp level?

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - is this related to an actual issue you are facing or are you just curious?

Answer (score 3):

They don't. And usually nothing on the client pc even does, as it merely asks its configured resolver (usually the ISP's caching nameserver) for an A/CNAME record.

And *that* resolver takes care of resolving the name, generally traversing from the root (which has many nameservers), to .com (also has many), then amazon.com (also has many), at each stage picking a random one to query, possibly trying another one if the first one returns a SERVFAIL or causes any other error to appear (except for NXDOMAIN or NODATA).

Comment: So the DNS servers will chose the NS server at random, and will pick the next one if they get back an error?

Comment: Generally, they tend to do something similar to that (usually not quite random, but something approaching that).